# programmatic creation of SetExpression fields in OpenOffice.org Writer

Tags: openoffice.org, uno

I'm trying to define "variables" in an openoffice document, and I must be doing something wrong because when I try to display the value of the variable using a field, I only get an empty string.

Here's the code I'm using (using the Python UNO bridge). The interesting bit is the second function.

```python
import time
import subprocess
import logging
import os
import sys
import uno
from com.sun.star.text.SetVariableType import STRING

def get_uno_model(): # helper function to connect to OOo. Only interesting 
                     # if you want to reproduce the issue locally, 
                     # don't spend time on this one
    try:
        model = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    except NameError:
        pass # we are not running in a macro
    # get the uno component context from the PyUNO runtime
    localContext = uno.getComponentContext()

    # create the UnoUrlResolver
    resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
                                    "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )

    # connect to the running office
    try:
        ctx = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;"
                               "urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
    except:
        cmd = ['soffice', '--writer', '-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;']
        popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        time.sleep(1)
        ctx = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;"
                               "urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
    smgr = ctx.ServiceManager

    # get the central desktop object
    desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)

    # access the current writer document
    model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
    return model

def build_variable(model, name, value):
    # find or create a TextFieldMaster with the correct name
    master_prefix = u"com.sun.star.text.fieldmaster.SetExpression"
    variable_names = set([_name.split('.')[-1] 
                          for _name in model.TextFieldMasters.ElementNames
                          if _name.startswith(master_prefix)])
    master_name = u'%s.%s' % (master_prefix, name)
    if name not in variable_names:
        master = model.createInstance(master_prefix)
        master.Name = name
    else:
        master = model.TextFieldMasters.getByName(master_name)

    # create the SetExpression field
    field = model.createInstance(u'com.sun.star.text.textfield.SetExpression')
    field.attachTextFieldMaster(master)
    field.IsVisible = True
    field.IsInput = False
    field.SubType = STRING
    field.Content = value
    return field

model = get_uno_model() # local function to connect to OpenOffice
text = model.Text
field = build_variable(model, u'Toto', 'nice variable')
text.insertTextContent(text.getEnd(), field, False)
```

This code works somehow (unless I removed too much), but if I manually insert a field to display the value of Toto I don't get the 'nice variable' string that I expect, and the field which is inserted has no value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is missing setting the SubType property of the master field to STRING after the creation of the master field.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
field.CurrentPresentation = value
```

let us know if this solves your issue, thanks.